# Mobile Number Regular Expression for HTML 5 pattern

Tags: regex, html

I try to make a regular expression for my above value format but still it not match my regular expression against below value. Can any one help me for give me regular expression that match below type of format with allow 0 to 9 digit , space , () character For HTML 5 Pattern.

value:  (999) 999-9999

Order Wise Character:

---

A) First Character : (
B) Three digit 0 to 9
C) Character: )
D) Space
E) Three digit 0 to 9
F) Character: -
G) Four digit 0 to 9

Any help me for solving this issue.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/dYEA7a/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\([0-9]{3}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$`

Detail :

Begining `^`
A) `\(`
B) `[0-9]{3}`
C) `\)`
D) `\s`
E) `[0-9]{3}`
F) `-`
G) `[0-9]{4}`
End `$`